# C/Java/etc. style arrays in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, data-structures, nsarray, primitive

I know Apple is big on having you use `NS` objects instead of true primitive types, but I need the capabilities of an array (namely direct access of items at indices). However, it seems that they are so very keen on using `NS` objects that I can't find a single tutorial online or in a textbook about how to use basic primitive arrays. **I want something that does things like this does in Java**:

```
String inventory[] = new String[45];

inventory[5] = "Pickaxe";
inventory[12] = "Dirt";
inventory[8] = "Cobblestone";

inventory[12] = null;

System.out.println("There are " + inventory.length + " slots in inventory: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(inventory));
```

The following is the closest I've gotten in Objective-C, but it won't run properly:

```
NSString *inventory[45];

inventory[5] = @"Pickaxe";
inventory[12] = @"Dirt";
inventory[8] = @"Cobblestone";

inventory[12] = nil;

NSArray *temp = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:inventory count:45];
NSLog(@"There are %i slots in inventory: %@", [temp count], [temp description]);
```

Also, if at all possible, is there something in O-C that will give me the count of non-null/non-nil objects in the array? (This way, I can tell how much space is left in the inventory so that the player can't pack away anything if it's full)

Comment: It's natural that it doesn't work. [NSArray arrayWithObjects:inventory]; would have required that `inventory` be a list of variadic arguments. User [NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] instead.

Comment: Don't forget that objective-c is built on top of C so any standard C code will work.  Just search for an example of a C array if you aren't sure how to use one.

Comment: @H2CO3 thanks for that! However, it still throws an exception for putting a `nil` value in there

Comment: That's your fault anyway! Collection objects *do* throw exceptions upon being given `nil`, and this behaviour is documented. You should check for nil before passing it to the initializer methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

typically, you would use `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray`, although you could also use C arrays.

`NSArray` (and most Foundation collections) cannot contain `nil` entries - you can use `NSPointerArray` (OS X) if you need `nil` values, or simply use `[NSNull null]` in an `NSArray` to designate `nil`.

Here's your program using an `NSArray`:

```
NSMutableArray * inventory = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSUInteger idx = 0; idx < 45; ++idx) {
  [inventory addObject:[NSNull null]];
}

[inventory replaceObjectAtIndex:5 withObject:@"Pickaxe"];
[inventory replaceObjectAtIndex:12 withObject:@"Dirt"];
[inventory replaceObjectAtIndex:8 withObject:@"Cobblestone"];

[inventory replaceObjectAtIndex:12 withObject:[NSNull null]];

NSArray *temp = [NSArray arrayWithObject:inventory];
NSLog(@"There are %i slots in inventory: %@", [temp count], [temp description]);
```

---

> Also, if at all possible, is there something in O-C that will give me the count of non-null/non-nil objects in the array?

An NSArray is a CFArray - they are "toll free bridged". Use `CFArrayGetCountOfValue` with `[NSNull null]` as the value to seek. Most of the CF-APIs are available in the NS-APIs, but not this one. You could easily wrap it in a category, if needed often.

Comment: when it tries to make the `NSArray`, it says `Program received signal:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS.` and exits.

Comment: @Supuhstar ah - i missed that. updated. that was taken from the original. you want `arrayWithObject:`, not `arrayWithObjects:` there.  you need to nil-terminate `arrayWithObjects:`, like so: `NSArray *temp = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:inventory, nil];`

Comment: awesome! I'm going to use this system, now :3

Answer (score 2):

Use c-style arrays. Any c code will work in objective c. Try not to mix objective c style objects with c style code unless you are very careful. The memory management stuff gets weird, and it is easy to get confused on object types vs. primitives.

Comment: ... so go read a book, or google "C array tutorial"? SO isn't the place to get people to personally teach you material that you can easily research yourself.

Comment: I just wanted a snippet, jeeze >.> If someone asked me for a sample of Java, HTML, CSS, VB, etc. code, I'd gladly write it out.